# Adding an object to an ArrayList from a different class (Chess in Java)

Tags: java, arraylist

I am writing a Chess program in Java. In my Board class, which deals with all movements of the Piece, I created a function called movePiece that moves a piece to a specific location and captures the enemy block if it exists on that location. The function for the movePiece looks like this:

```
public void movePiece(int x, int y, Piece pieceToMove) {

    if(pieceToMove.canMove(board, this.x, this.y, x, y)){ //Check if the piece canMove to the location

        if(board[x][y] == null) { //Check if the location is empty

            removePiece(this.x, this.y);
            board[x][y] = pieceToMove;

        } else {

            if(board[x][y].getColor() != pieceToMove.getColor()) { //Check if the location is occupied by an enemy

                removePiece(this.x, this.y);
                board[x][y] = pieceToMove;  

            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid Move");
            }
        }

    } else {

        System.out.println("Invalid Move");

    }
}
```

It works fine, but I wanted to keep in track of the captured enemy Piece in an ArrayList. So, I created an ArrayList capturedList inside a Player class to keep in track of it, and tried to add

```
        if(board[x][y].getColor() != pieceToMove.getColor()) { //Check if the location is occupied by an enemy

            addCapturedPiece(board[x][y], capturedList); <--- THIS LINE
            removePiece(this.x, this.y);
            board[x][y] = pieceToMove;  

        }
```

But this did not work because capturedList is inside the Player class. Is there a way to make this work smoothly?

Comment: what is `addCapturedPiece` and what is the type of `board[x][y]`?

Comment: `movePiece` does something, the result of which you want to know ... how would you make `movePiece` tell the caller that something happened, that they might be interested?

Comment: addCapturedPiece is a method that I made in Player class to keep track of the pieces that the player has captured. The type of the board[x][y] is Piece. I am having problem using the addCapturedPiece in the Board class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make `addCapturedPiece` a method in the Player class. Then, the player that is moving the current piece can call that method and add the piece to his/her specific `capturedList`. For instance:

```
/***** in Player class *****/
private LinkedList<Piece> capturedList = new LinkedList<Piece>();
// ...
private static void addCapturedPiece(Piece p)
{
    capturedList.add(p);
}

/***** in your movePiece method *****/
player1.addCapturedPiece(board[x][y]);
```